# how to test text against a bad word list using jquery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate textarea/input against list of words.
I created

```
var badwordlist = new Array("blue", "Blue", "BLUE",
"ASS", "drugs", "aciphex", "nude");
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("badWord", function(value) {
            return !new RegExp(badwordlist.join('|')).test(value);
        }, "Please remove bad words.");
```

this is working fine. I am having issue if i type greenblue it will still give me error. While i only want to check blue not greenblue. same thing with ass as class or assessment.

Comment: Is "blue" a "bad word"?

Comment: its a placeholder, i suppose.

Comment: i am just testing different swearing words. I don't want to use those words here. Blue is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try checking the other way around?

```
var badwordlist = new Array("blue", "ass", "drugs", "aciphex", "nude");

alert((new RegExp("blue", "i")).test("[" + badwordlist.join("][") + "]"));
alert((new RegExp("greenblue", "i")).test("[" + badwordlist.join("][") + "]"));
alert((new RegExp("ass", "i")).test("[" + badwordlist.join("][") + "]"));
alert((new RegExp("class", "i")).test("[" + badwordlist.join("][") + "]"));
```

Comment: IMTheNachoMan I am using jquery validation api. I created custom validation method. How can i use your suggested code to test if it works in my method?

Comment: I am not sure as I am not sure how jQuery's validation API works. But it looks like you just need to use the Regular Expression I provided.

Comment: IMTheNachoMan, Thanks for your answer. RegExp look for a pattern. When i removed RegExp and i used .test( my_textarea.value). It worked they way i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code worked for me,

```
var blacklist = /\b(word|word|word|word|word|word|word|word|word|word|word|word)\b/; /* many more banned words... */

jQuery.validator.addMethod("badwordcheck", function(value) {
    return !blacklist.test(value.toLowerCase());
}, "Please remove inappropriate language before submitting.");
```